# Netbeans not finding PrimeFaces 5.3 in frameworks

Tags: jsf, primefaces, frameworks, netbeans-8

I am running NetBeans 8.0.2.

I'm currently trying to update the JavaServer Faces (2.2) to point at the PrimeFaces 5.3 Libary. However, it fails to recognize that I have a 5.3 library.

[image]

However, the following dialogue searches for Primeface libaries, and only detects 5.0.

[image]

However, I very clearly have this library defined as shown:

[image]

Anyone have a fix for this? The library is picked up fine by the project itself, and it recognizes the Primeface imports.

Comment: I have the same problem with Netbeans 8.1. With this version it is even not more possible to click on "More..." button to select a specific version of Primefaces !

Answer (score 1):

I work on Netbeans 8.1 using MAVEN and I have encountered same problem.

My problem is that Primefaces version is currently defined in PARENT POM referenced in APPLICATION POM and that Netbeans is not able to find correct version in PARENT POM but only in APPLICATION POM.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.company.tlga</groupId>
    <artifactId>tlga</artifactId>
    <version>1.18-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

Explanations:

I have 2 POM, a application POM and a parent POM.

Primefaces dependencies are defined in PARENT POM and are not defined in APPLICATION POM.

I have moved Primefaces dependencies from PARENT POM to application POM and I have declared in Netbeans properties that I use JSF framework and Primefaces component.

At this moment, Netbeans has replaced Primefaces version in application POM with 5.0 version !!!

I have then replaced this very old version by 6.3-SNAPSHOT version and I have build my application again and now all works well.

The  in all my xhtml files are not more RED underlined and new widgets as  that don't exist on Primefaces 5.0 are now selectable.

Comment: @kukeltje: I have readed your comment and I have changed my answer to remove "complexity" word.

Answer (score 0):

Check your dependencies. Maybe try removing and adding the primefaces dependency through your POM or by deleting the dependency and then right clicking on your dependency folder and selecting add.